# Multiple proposals assigned to the same study section in NIH

Tags: peer-review, funding, research-proposal, nih

I would like to know everybody's ideas about having multiple NIH proposals being reviewed in one [study section/scientific review group](https://www.niaid.nih.gov/grants-contracts/know-your-audience) (group of peer reviewers that evaluate proposals on a particular topic) at the same time.

These days I believe many people are writing multiple proposals during the same submission cycle, and it is hard to always gear them toward different study sections given the focus of the lab. I often hear people saying that having multiple proposals in the same study section is bad, but is it true? Can someone share their experiences?